# assign declared array variable

Tags: bash

(bash noobie here)

In bash I am successful creating an array with database tables and then looping through them. I want to declare this array at the top of my script and then assign it later to another variable.

```
my_databases=(value1 value2 value3)
```

Looping through this works fine with `for i in "${my_databases[@]}"`

**The problem is here:**
Instead of looping through `my_databases` I have a step in between and I want to assign the array to a variable `new_array`.

```
new_array=$my_databases
```

Now when I loop through this `new_array`, the script fails after the first array value. 
How can I assign a declared array to a new variable correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a new array variable, assign the values of the old array to the new array like this:

```
my_databases=(value1 value2 value3)
new_array=("${my_databases[@]}")
```

If you use

```
new_array=$my_databases
```

the new variable will not be an array (unless you use `declare -a new_array=$my_databases`) and `$my_databases` only expands to the first value of the array.

Comment: bash handles this `new_array=$my_databases` like this: `new_array=${my_databases[0]}`

Comment: Thanks. I played with the other comment as well to see what happens. Works great!

Comment: @Daniel When debugging it can help to display the attributes and values of the variables with `declare -p name […]` like `declare -p my_databases new_array`.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to create a *copy* of the array. Then use @Freddy's answer.

If you want to create a *reference* to the *same* data, recent versions of bash have "namerefs":

```
$ my_databases=(value1 value2 value3)
$ declare -n new_array=my_databases
```

Then:

```
$ for i in "${!new_array[@]}"; do printf "%d\t%s\n" $i "${new_array[i]}"; done
0   value1
1   value2
2   value3
```

but if you alter the first array, the changes are seen in the "new" one:

```
$ my_databases[2]="updated value 3"
$ for i in "${!new_array[@]}"; do printf "%d\t%s\n" $i "${new_array[i]}"; done
0   value1
1   value2
2   updated value 3
```

Comment: Thanks. I like this. Good for manipulation of the array. Thanks for sharing hat.